# The timezone could not be found in the database

Tags: datetime

This one is new to me. I've got the timezone set in my admin panel to Denver but I get this this error when I try using a global in my template...

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (End Date) at position 0 (E): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Here is my code in the template

```
{{ endDate | date("U") }}
```

My global is called End Date (endDate) and is using a date field type

Comment: What happens when you do `{{ endDate }}`? Is this a custom template global from a plugin or is it a field on a Craft global set, because those you usually access with `{{ myGlobalSet.endDate }}`.

Comment: Hey @brunam, did you solve this in the meantime?

Comment: your suggestion was correct actually. forget the the myGlobalSet part

Comment: Good to see you solved this. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a custom template global from a plugin or is it a field on a Craft global set, because those you usually access with `{{ myGlobalSet.endDate }}`.